# Why do they call them Thunks?

Tags: function, thunk

A Thunk is often defined as any piece of code (usually a function) that delays the evaluation of an expression.

In JavaScript, a Thunk might look like `(a,b)=>a+b`, but they exist in many different languages.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk

So, my question is why do they call them "Thunk"s? Is there a reason or is it just a random word someone chose.

Answer (score 1):

According to Wikipedia,

The term originated as a jocular derivative of "think".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk#cite_note-1

According to the New Hackers Dictionary and urban legend, the word “Thunk” is a jocular derivative of the past tense of “Think”, usually “thought.” They are so called because the computations within the function have already been thought out, or “thunk”, in advance
[https://books.google.ca/books?id=g80P_4v4QbIC&lpg=PA445&vq=445&pg=PA445#v=snippet&q=445&f=false]

"Well, I'm a thinkin' and thinkin', till there's nothin' I ain't thunk." - Violent Femmes